# Django Aggregation: Summation of Multiplication of two related fields

Tags: django, django-orm

This is my model:

```
class Inventory(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey("product.Product", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    count = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

I basically want to get the sum of `product__cost` * `count` for all rows.

I would normally do:

```
Inventory.objects.all().aggregate(sum=Sum(F('fieldA') * F('fieldB')))['sum']
```

but running this with `product__cost` as fieldA gives me `integer out of range`.

How do I achieve this result correctly?

Comment: Is it possible that you have mixed types between `product__cost` and the other field you're multiplying it by? I can confirm that your syntax is correct - I have a similar model structure in an app I manage, and your query/aggregation worked fine - *but only if the fields were of the same type*: integer, or float. (`None` values caused no problems.) If they were different types, I would get a FieldError, "Expression contains mixed types. You must set an output field." - but you have a different error, so I'm not sure what might be going on there. Thought I'd suggest this, though.